# Using logs to help diagnose freeze: what to look for?

Tags: boot, kde, ubuntu-studio

Ubuntu Studio 20.10, KDE Plasma 5.19.5

Getting random(?) freezes and I'm viewing the logs to try and see what might be happening prior to the freeze. It's happened four times today, and each time I have to hard boot with the power button.

I'm viewing /var/log/syslog and Xorg.0.log, but I can't identify in either file something logged with each reboot that would tell me "that line previous is the last thing recorded." I would expect a logged "...system starting xxx blah blah blah" in either, but can't find it.

Is there such a thing? Is there a line I can look for that's written with each boot-up?

EDIT: with KSysguard open, I don't see any red flags. CPU 80%-ish, memory 2gb out of 8gb, swap file not even touched.

Comment: How good is your fan/cooling system? How dusty is the inside of your computer? Suspect overheating or power supply problems, both of which halt the CPU before anything can get logged.

Comment: Try to note the EXACT time of a freeze. When you can access logs, look at the minute or two before the freeze time. Look for ANY kind of warning or error message. Look for time-gaps in the logs that might have occurred during the freeze. Look for warning or error messages that occur immediately after the freeze. Look for a log interrupted by random characters. Review multiple freezes and look for patterns. Reboots create an enormous amount of log activity, you might not be scrolling back far enough.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: My question would be the same no matter what version of ubuntu I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have a much easier time if you use `journalctl` or KSystemLog instad of investigating log files raw.

Filtering to the last-before-current boot and sorting by newest first:

`journalctl -b -1 -r`

You may also want to limit the search to a specific program you suspect (`_COMM=`), and focus on messages of higher severity (lower `-p`) first. If you know the exact time the crash happened you can further narrow it down by the timestamp (`--since`, `--until`).

See the man page or the many online tutorials for more info on the options available for `journalctl`.

If you prefer a graphical application: KSystemLog; the available sort and filter buttons should be self-explanatory.